# CultureInfo name for each country

Tags: culture, cultureinfo

I have country list with two letter code like 'US' and  and three letter code like 'USA'.
I just want to assign all 239 countries have the locale code like en-US (not es-US).

I tried the iterate on:

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
```

then:

```
 var country = countries.Where(c => c.CodeIso3 == region.ThreeLetterISORegionName).FirstOrDefault();
```

it doesnt work, to much override.

how to assign the 239 countries code to with is major(or default) language?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that. That is because there is no such thing as default language for many of the countries you have in mind.
For example, US does not have an **official** language. Although English is used by majority of its citizens, it is not *default*. The other interesting example would be Switzerland. Its citizens use French, German, Italian and Romansh. None of these is *default*.

That is the reason why there is no such API.

### Edit:

As I said before, in many countries there is no such think as ***default*** language. I even gave an example of the country which has more than one **major** language (German and French). To all of you that still can't understand that ***this really does not make sense***, I will give you a clue on how to guess the most probable language:

[Common Locale Data Repository Territory-Language Information](http://unicode.org/cldr/charts/supplemental/territory_language_information.html)

If you still cannot understand why restricting to one language per country is probably not the best of ideas, I give up.